# Matplotlib Control Spacing Between Bars

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to insert spacing between two specific bars but cannot find any easy way to do this. I can manually add a dummy row with with 0 height to create and empty space but doesn't give me control of how wide the space should be.  Is there a more programmatic method I can use to control the spacing between bars at any position?

**Example Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

mydict = {
    'Event': ['Running', 'Swimming', 'Biking', '', 'Hiking', 'Jogging'],
    'Completed': [2, 4, 3, 0, 7, 9],
    'Participants': [10, 20, 35, 0, 10, 20]}

df = pd.DataFrame(mydict).set_index('Event')
df = df.assign(Completion=(df.Completed / df.Participants) * 100)

plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 4))

print(df.index)
ax = sns.barplot(x=df.Completion, y=df.index, color="orange", orient='h')

plt.xticks(rotation=60)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

**Example DataFrame Output:**

```
          Completed  Participants  Completion
Event                                        
Running           2            10   20.000000
Swimming          4            20   20.000000
Biking            3            35    8.571429
                  0             0         NaN
Hiking            7            10   70.000000
Jogging           9            20   45.000000
```

**Example output** (blue arrows added outside of code to show where empty row was added.):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can access the position of the boxes and the name of the labels. Then modify them. You may find an more general way depending on your use case, but this works for the given example.

```
#define a function to add space starting a specific label
def add_space_after(ax, label_shift='', extra_space=0):
    bool_space = False
    # get postion of current ticks
    ticks_position = np.array(ax.get_yticks()).astype(float)
    # iterate over the boxes/label
    for i, (patch, label) in enumerate(zip(ax.patches, ax.get_yticklabels())):
        # if the label to start the shift found
        if label.get_text()==label_shift: bool_space = True
        # reposition the boxes and the labels afterward
        if bool_space:
            patch.set_y(patch.get_y() + extra_space)
            ticks_position[i] += extra_space
    # in the case where the spacing is needed
    if bool_space:
        ax.set_yticks(ticks_position)
        ax.set_ylim([ax.get_ylim()[0]+extra_space, ax.get_ylim()[1]])

#note: no more blank row
mydict = {
    'Event': ['Running', 'Swimming', 'Biking', 'Hiking', 'Jogging'],
    'Completed': [2, 4, 3, 7, 9],
    'Participants': [10, 20, 35, 10, 20]}
df = pd.DataFrame(mydict).set_index('Event')
df = df.assign(Completion=(df.Completed / df.Participants) * 100)

ax = sns.barplot(x=df.Completion, y=df.index, color="orange", orient='h')
plt.xticks(rotation=60)
plt.tight_layout()

#use the function
add_space_after(ax, 'Hiking', 0.6)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for taking time to look at this.  I am not getting the desired results from the function. Instead of adding space after Hiking it is adding space after Biking. Also if I increase the space to 0.9 it also increases the space after Jogging. Any idea why that is the case?

Comment: @MBasith so the first problem is more a bad naming of the function, it should be called add_space_before because as you can see, the name entered is `Hiking` so it adds space before

Comment: @MBasith for the second problem with 0.9, it is related to this line `ax.set_ylim([ax.get_ylim()[0]+extra_space, ax.get_ylim()[1]])`, I have not been testing all the cases so can't tell what to put exactly here try `ax.set_ylim([ax.get_ylim()[0]+extra_space/2, ax.get_ylim()[1]])` if it is not too big number

Comment: That worked like a charm!  The function also provides the flexibility I was looking for. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @MBasith It may need a bit of tweaking depending on your needs, but hope the general idea gives lead for it :)